# Symfony2 & SonataMedia: current field not linked to an admin

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

I've been tring the last days to make SonataMedia works with Symfony 2.0.16... with no success. Googling around seems like no much people use that bundle or there's a tutorial or an how-to that I'm not aware of, cause I don't get to much info about the error messages I've got so far.

Anyway, my last attempt gave the next error message:

```
The current field `path` is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity : ``
```

"path" is the field used to save the file image (relative) path.

**AttachmentAdmin.php**

```
<?php

class AttachmentAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add(
                'path',
                'sonata_type_collection',
                array(
                    'required' => true
                ),
                array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
                    'targetEntity' => 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia',
                    'link_parameters' => array(
                        'context' => 'attachment'
                    )
                )
            )
            ->add('notes', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
        ;
    }

    // other methods
}
```

**Attachment.php**

```
<?php

class Attachment
{
    // other properties

    /**
     * @var string $path
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $path;

    // other methods

    /**
     * Set path
     *
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        foreach ($path as $ent) {
            $ent->setAttachment($this);
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia $path
     */
    public function addPath(\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia $path)
    {
        $this->path[] = $path;
    }
}
```

**GalleryHasMedia.php**

```
<?php

class GalleryHasMedia extends BaseGalleryHasMedia
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @var File
     */
    private $attachment;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Mercury\CargoRecognitionBundle\Entity\Attachment $attachment
     * @return \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia
     */
    public function setAttachment(\Mercury\CargoRecognitionBundle\Entity\Attachment $attachment = null)
    {
        $this->attachment = $attachment;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return \Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\File
     */
    public function getAttachment()
    {
        return $this->attachment;
    }
}
```

**services.yml**

```
    mercury.cargo_recognition.admin.attachment:
        class: Mercury\CargoRecognitionBundle\Admin\AttachmentAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: General, label: Attachments }
        arguments: [ null, Mercury\CargoRecognitionBundle\Entity\Attachment, "MercuryCargoRecognitionBundle:AttachmentAdmin" ]
```

Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 5):

Just a wild guess, create an admin class for `GalleryHasMedia` entity.

Comment: I've never seen that a GalleryHasMediaAdmin file, but I'm gonna give it a wild try ;-)

Comment: Figure it out yet?  Same issue.

Comment: This is the answer. You needed to created GalleryHasMediaAdmin and then add it to services.yml

Answer (score 3):

You need to add admin_code like this

```
$formMapper
        ->add(
            'path',
            'sonata_type_collection',
            array(
                'required' => true
            ),
            array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable' => 'position',
                'targetEntity' => 'Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia',
                'link_parameters' => array(
                    'context' => 'attachment'
                ),
                'admin_code' => 'sonata.media.admin.gallery_has_media' // this will be your admin class service name
            )
        )
        ->add('notes', 'textarea', array('required' => false))
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You  are trying to apply '**sonata_type_collection**' on field '***path***' of ***same entity class*** '**attachment**' , while '**sonata_type_collection**' is for collection of embeded form of different class .
So you will have to one more entity class suppose '**AttachmentCollection**' and in this particular **AttachmentsCollection's** admin class, you should embed the '***Attachment***' class admin ..
 example:

```
class AttachmentsCollection extends Admin
{
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
   ->add('attachments', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                        'required' => false,
                        'type_options' => array('delete' => true)
                    ), array(
                        'edit' => 'inline',
                        'inline' => 'table',
                        'sortable' => 'position',
                    ));
     }
  }
```

And also do't forget to do mapping '**one to many**' or '**many to many**' mapping between '**AttachmentsCollection**' and '**Attachments**' supposing that one '**AttachmentsCollection**' has many '**Attachments**' object ..

Comment: Remember that the issue was posted on September 2012. Not the current version of SonataMedia nor Symfony2. I drop SonataMediaBundle a year ago for VichUploaderBundle (which is simpler).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like what you need to do is pass in an `admin_code` which is the name of the admin section (`mercury.cargo_recognition.admin.attachment`) in the `$fieldDescriptionOptions` parameter to the `add()` method.

Comment: I solved the issue long time ago, but I don't remember what was wrong and what I did to fix it. 

I'm using vichUploaderBundler right now (which suits perfectly with my database structure).

Answer (score 0):

As old as this issue is, I'll still add something on how this can be resolved to help anyone else who might run into it. The root issue is that the $path targetEntity("Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia") doesn't have an admin class.

To resolve it, add an admin class for your targetEntity:

```
class GalleryHasMediaAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('attachment', 'file')
        ;
    }

    // other methods
}
```

Then add that admin class to services.yml

```
mercury.cargo_recognition.admin.galleryhadmedia:
    class: Mercury\CargoRecognitionBundle\Admin\GalleryHasMediaAdmin
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: General, label: 'Gallery Has Media' }
    arguments: [ null, Mercury\CargoRecognitionBundle\Entity\GalleryHasMedia, "MercuryCargoRecognitionBundle:GalleryHasMediaAdmin" ]
```

Comment: Unrelated to this particular question, this solution holds if your property is mapped to a targetEntity. Make sure you set-up mapping first (If you are using doctrine ODM, like doctrine_phpcr, the mapping is done using something like:

@PHPCR\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Acme\DemoBundle\Document\TheTargetClass", cascade={"persist"})

Answer (score 0):

if your admin class for GalleryHasMedia is not yet created and you have not put the service code in your config.yml file then first do that and try again. I had the same issue and got resolved this way.

Answer (score 0):

Five years later, it's worth noting that the "target entity" itself appears to be blank in the error text. We get a set of backticks, rather than an entity name.

(I am working on an old app and getting a similar error right now. I have generated an admin class for my entity and registered it in the correct place, and it looks like the app is having trouble figuring out what my target entity *is* -- which by default prevents it from finding the related admin class. I'm sort of tearing my hair out over this one and will probably put up a bounty tomorrow on it.)